# how to install and configure cvblob into opencv to use it with python?

Tags: python, opencv

hi I have been trying to use the cvblob python examples given in the github site
https://github.com/oostendo/cvblob-python

but I'm getting this error I don't know why:

```
 from _cvblob import *
ImportError: No module named _cvblob
```

any help I'll be thankful

Comment: hi rosa, lean back a second, and rethink if you want that module at all. cvBlob as well as it's python wrapper are outdated, and depend on the deprecated c-api. this again will force you to use the old cv api (which will be gone in the next opencv version). cv2 probably already contains all functionality needed to achieve the same goals.

Comment: and if you see a github repo, that's not maintained in the last 3 years, move on quickly ...

Comment: @ berak the problem is that i couldn't find any examples that fit my need in detecting objects so that i can at least learn from it except cvblob,any advices